# I received harassing emails and I want to know who sent them

Tags: email

I am not a tech-savvy person, although I do find it fascinating and have tried to become cyber-savvy today.  I received three emails today that were vaguely harassing, and I think I have an idea of who sent them... but they were sent through guerrilla mail. Here's the expanded header of the first email; I have tried tracing the IP address, but it shows me different locations on different websites. Anybody have ideas?

```
Delivered-To: e*****u@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a19:fc08:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id a8csp6103293lfi;
        Wed, 6 Mar 2019 05:49:01 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: APXvYqwbLFHmxuX83npU9yF6XaM8A4fIt1bTWdPCgandfxl2/jdgMqeCJYaOxFlyN5GY+p0135fi
X-Received: by 2002:aed:3536:: with SMTP id a51mr5727604qte.308.1551880141560;
        Wed, 06 Mar 2019 05:49:01 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1551880141; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=1D85G7VjDBahB5xfkaYMaWd4djLy+4UjLvx8Qx3lMA4P3VCgD8MrDPIkolmquCJdHQ
         Rtle79SnAEqEEl29gfiC69GNXBuYpe5iKFc4rOAreUKQ5utlgDKMqyhfdxT+5+mMb79V
         e4JY+5QBExAt7s2ZwjW+JtHIjvb3XKjlMlTHXaLz0Q/usYtuWhp+4FTgQbCueZjNewyA
         qGpTtrr+JIOFTQFbacQVIgdmQEdDAh/f2re2pWBjcMAWlfKszQZBxzn/jp8X/5SrqOKv
         SI9xr97/ueXUBtK/Vr4Upp5rTqWmZ5eNtdphP6MYFlKgVBB1i0mXt6JV+8ZN/VRVl33a
         fkcA==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=dkim-signature:content-transfer-encoding:subject:from:to:date
         :message-id:mime-version;
        bh=mXGVzoU+fHoNxojT16ZkaT8DqGHb+9sP1WX+Whq5zMo=;
        b=Et9sWIVePsEEUxg7zop0+5vh+6lRprBiL+dNudhJ+JRQHu8baHEAdgJJXIgjmT44Fk
         /QccG0hFJRF/ZRe876OkaTCU4IqppAQe5H1WKMO501ANX/UzBvUQ0DBdUxKdwmp+UH+5
         ZJHoqkrgOqlPjXGkJ3T1uMhaLWWXtzX809CnK/4nwSdcbXQ/o8tMQkeG6U3AXwvuXx3h
         N3Pm2WfHjdydeCmX79ytIMUOsK9vuLTeIaG2dWhR/LjlGzjy6NmxjysWXC1LkVRp0Y76
         p5jLXld+OzBVqXvMeUAfHqgVT57FTvgOcYat59Sp7jEY69G0uFziU90JepEk2suDrE6c
         kjgQ==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@guerrillamail.com header.s=highgrade header.b=uD04+jTu;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of hekjtb+4bg5qgb7oy8yk@guerrillamail.com designates 2607:5300:60:689e:: as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=hekjtb+4bg5qgb7oy8yk@guerrillamail.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=guerrillamail.com
Return-Path: <hekjtb+4bg5qgb7oy8yk@guerrillamail.com>
Received: from mail.guerrillamail.com ([2607:5300:60:689e::])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id m39si965074qta.117.2019.03.06.05.49.01
        for <e*******u@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 06 Mar 2019 05:49:01 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of hekjtb+4bg5qgb7oy8yk@guerrillamail.com designates 2607:5300:60:689e:: as permitted sender) client-ip=2607:5300:60:689e::;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@guerrillamail.com header.s=highgrade header.b=uD04+jTu;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of hekjtb+4bg5qgb7oy8yk@guerrillamail.com designates 2607:5300:60:689e:: as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=hekjtb+4bg5qgb7oy8yk@guerrillamail.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=guerrillamail.com
Received: by 167.114.101.158 with HTTP; Wed, 06 Mar 2019 13:49:00 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-ID: <28b743128eb51823e3d110c83a895db8d659@guerrillamail.com>
Date: Wed, 06 Mar 2019 13:49:00 +0000
To: "e******u@gmail.com" <e*******u@gmail.com>
From: <hekjtb+4bg5qgb7oy8yk@guerrillamail.com>
Subject: Wow
X-Originating-IP: [174.229.18.171]
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-Domain-Signer: PHP mailDomainSigner 0.2-20110415 <http://code.google.com/p/php-mail-domain-signer/>
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; s=highgrade; d=guerrillamail.com; l=297; t=1551880140; c=relaxed/relaxed; h=to:from:subject; bh=mXGVzoU+fHoNxojT16ZkaT8DqGHb+9sP1WX+Whq5zMo=; b=uD04+jTuxIo6m5vzAzQJnf+nuEW+9LGfJ11bn97KSyBBLitBRtyARSftheZWOMVden5Ow9xyLufx rtsktzXWV6C7POh6LVTN2ONXmyad2f5pN0MBYECr96B/mfYXGMoEbhAfCkPoNUpvbD+5twK1+7bc vltPlkBaKdSIJGXco2hnTUUjUUtt4DYr/7py9R6a0k6uMPKifkudZbsaEDjiiJxR325ws4Ux99D3 KsvbeJn92v407n2EnO05hALCaPNPECi6S1CDtNbzaNGOp8LRA2plqArOrXxdxhQIQ0iQO4gX8I0U 156R80DJiumsOP9afJ4DUqaHwlBBWKJUCZTVlw==

So isn=E2=80=99t your husband an attorney who advocates for fracking?  He r=
epresents shale industries, right?  Wait until this goes viral.





----
Sent using Guerrillamail.com
Block or report abuse: https://www.guerrillamail.com//abuse/?a=3DRFN1CA8FQq=
E1jwO1%2BXJRcRvK
```

Comment: The IP address 174.229.18.171 seems to belong to Verizon Wireless, so it _might_ have been sent from the Verizon network.  Different Geo-IP databases give different answers about the location.  https://www.iplocation.net/  It's likely not possible to determine much beyond this without court orders.

Comment: Expoising your email address like this is likely to increase your spam load. I have submitted an edit suggestion to blot out your address from the sample.

Comment: @tripleee I have accepted your change for modifying the email address earlier. Steve Sether: It could also be a proxy server for mobile data.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot offer "interpret this email header for me" services because a) it's simply interpretting email protocols and not about security, b) we would be flooded with random headers, and c) the people who can determine who sent them is the vendor.

Comment: John's answer below is really the only answer that we can realistically provide.

Answer (score 3):

While we can't see what address was typed into Guerrillamail to send it, we can see that Guerrillamail has a [Terms of Service](https://www.guerrillamail.com/tos/) that prohibits "harassing" emails:

> This service prohibits sending of messages, that:
>
> - are unsolicited commercial email (spam)
> - are harassing, abusive, defamatory, obscene, in bad faith, unethical or otherwise illegal content
> - distribute trojans, viruses or other malicious computer software
> - are intending to commit fraud, impersonating other persons, phishing, scams, or related crime
> - distribute intellectual property without ownership or a license to distribute such property
> - breach, in any way, the terms of service, privacy policy or rules of this web site or the recipients'
>
> Copyright violations, complaints or abuse reports should be reported
>   to us via our feedback systems described in the About Us sections.

This is the Contact info in their [About Us](https://www.guerrillamail.com/about) link:

> Contact
>
> Please use use Facebook / Twitter to contact us (English). Please note
>   that we cannot always reply - although we do our best.

If you felt threatened or harassed by that email, this seems to be the extent of your recourse.  Alternately, their post included a link at the bottom to report the email as abuse.  You may try clicking that as well.

Comment: No matter what's in the terms of service, offering *Disposable Temporary E-Mail Addresses* is inviting abusers.